# i want to generate a PDF file from banner image in Joomla1.5?

Tags: joomla1.5

From **Joomla1.5** i tried to generate a PDF file from index page banner image.

**When i click the banner image it will generate that banner into PDF file**
any one give me the solution for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org/) and make banner a link and redirect to any php page. In that link you should keep the details of the banner image and in the redirecting page trigger the function to download pdf file